# Jquery executes first line of code but then doesnt execute the rest

Tags: jquery

When I call the below function `Selectall`, the `alert` doesn't appear.

```
 function Selectall(){
     $("INPUT[id^='DefaultContent_checkAllWebObjectCheckBox_").on('change',   function () {

    $("INPUT[id^='DefaultContent_checkLstWebObjects_']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    alert('Hello');
});
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]?

Comment: Any errors in the console? maybe it doesn't complete the execution of the first line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: ok i minimized and verified, when the above function is called, alert doesnt get called.

Comment: `checked` is an attribute, use `.attr('checked')`, not `.prop()`. Also, use a `.each()` function to loop through the multiple inputs.

Comment: the propblem isnt with my checked line of code, the alert hello isnt firing

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb `checked` is also a property, and `prop()` should always be used over `attr()` where possible.

Comment: Your code as shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/hc6eepqs/. Please add an MCVE to your question. Note that if you're trying to set the inputs as selected you should set the checked property to `true`, not the value it already has.

Comment: Are you actually running the function? Where's the rest of your code, because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code, see @RoryMcCrossan's fiddle.

Comment: Is the first line actualy running?

Comment: yes the first line runs

Comment: You missed a apostrophe and bracket on the `.on('change')` function's selector:Not: `$("INPUT[id^='DefaultContent_checkAllWebObjectCheckBox_").` This: `$("INPUT[id^='DefaultContent_checkAllWebObjectCheckBox_']").`

Answer (score 0):

is this function just for select all? or would you like to toggle all (by selecting/deselecting)?

```
function Selectall() {
    $("INPUT[id^='DefaultContent_checkLstWebObjects_']").attr('checked', true);
}
```

if you would like to toggle all:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toogle_all" onclick="toggleAll(this)"/>
```

and your function would be like this:

```
function toggleAll(toggler) {
    $("INPUT[id^='DefaultContent_checkLstWebObjects_']").attr('checked', $(toggler).attr("checked"));
}
```